# Combine two Python codes

Tags: python

I am very new in python, but I have been able to make few useful python codes (at least useful for my work). I would like to combine two of my codes, but I have a hard time making it work, I think I am completely lost in how the code should looks like.

The first code basically takes a file, read it, extract to columns from it, and then write the columns in a new file. I repeat this with several files:

```
import sys
import re

filetowrite = sys.argv[1]
filetoread = sys.argv[2]

newfile = str(filetowrite) + ".txt"

openold = open(filetoread,"r")
opennew = open(newfile,"w")

rline = openold.readlines()

number = int(len(rline))
start = 0

for i in range (len(rline)) :
    if "2theta" in rline[i] :
        start = i

opennew.write ("q" + "\t" + "I" + "\n")
opennew.write ("1/A" + "\t" + "1/cm" + "\n")
opennew.write (str(filetowrite) + "\t" + str(filetowrite) + "\n")

for line in rline[start + 1 : number] :
    words = line.split()
    word1 = (words[1])
    word2 = (words[2])
    opennew.write (word1 + "\t" + word2 + "\n")

openold.close()
opennew.close()
```

The second code takes the new previously created files and combine them in a way in which the columns are next to each other in the final file.

```
import sys
from itertools import izip

filenames = sys.argv[2:]

filetowrite = sys.argv[1]

newfile = str(filetowrite) + ".txt"
opennew = open(newfile, "w")

files = map(open, filenames)

for lines in izip(*files):
    opennew.write(('\t'.join(i.strip() for i in lines))+"\n")
```

Any help in how to proceed to make a single code out of these two codes is highly appreciated.

All the best

Comment: Please make the code inline to your question above, don't use links!

Answer (score 2):

Make each file into a function in one larger file, then call the functions as necessary.  Make use of `__main__` to do that.

```
import sys
import re
from itertools import izip

def func_for_file1():
    # All of the code from File 1 goes here.

def func_for_file2():
    # ALl of the code from File 2 goes here.

def main():
   # Decide what order you want to call these methods.
   func_for_file1()
   func_for_file2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Makoto, thanks for the help. However, I still have one question. Since both codes contain arguments that are given in certain order, how this would work in the combine code? Thanks

Comment: Makoto, I tried what you suggest, but I can make it work. Too many different errors

Comment: I don't see an issue with preserving the order of execution that your files have in the methods.  That should give you the exact same performance, unless you're doing other fancy stuff.  What I did was extract the flow of the files and that should work.  Be sure you're mimicking what those files would do standalone before pulling them into methods.